# Exchange stdout and stdin between two programs

Tags: bash, stdout, stdin

I'd like to make automation program for specific command, so I need to make them exchange stdout and stdin during their execution.

Let me explain, If there's a command that executes two programs simultaneously,

```
# cmd1 (pipe or redirection something) cmd2
```

`cmd1` sends stdout as stdin to `cmd2`, and then `cmd2` sends stdout as stdin to `cmd1`.

The output user received should be output of `cmd1`. How can I make this happen?

Comment: A pipe should work.  Could you show code from cmd1 and cmd2 where this doesn't work?

Comment: @AlexStiff On Linux, pipes are not bidirectional (but they are on some systems like Solaris and BSD, for instance). I think instead using [named pipes like the 32-vote solution here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53641/how-to-make-bidirectional-pipe-between-two-programs?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) would be a better, more portable, solution. Also, OP, this would be a better question for unix.stackexchange.com, I believe.

Comment: @AlexStiff I can process all of stdout from cmd1 on cmd2, but I can't send stdout from cmd2 to cmd1.

Comment: @JNevill I see, Thank you!

Comment: Here's [the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53646/22257) mentioned by JNevill.

Comment: @chepner Thanks! I didn't know you could anchor to answer. That's handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use FIFO files for this.

https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-mkfifo-command/

FIFO files allows you to name your pipe. You can creat 2 named pipes one for cmd1|cmd2 and the other for cmd2 | cmd1.